# UI-Select default placeholder than can change

Tags: html, angularjs

So I would like to set my placeholder to have a default value which I originally had, but I have a modal view which when I create a user it updates which is done due to the following code:

```
<ui-select-match class="ui-select-match" placeholder="Test">{{$select.selected.loginName}} </ui-select-match>
```

However I would like to have a value beforehand, such as please select an option, etc. I tried using:

```
attrs.$set('placeholder', userEntity.loginName)
```

But atlas, no success. I was wondering has anyone had this issue before and if so, is it possible to have a default placeholder which can then be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-attr-placeholder` to bind the attribute value to an angularJS `expression`, validate if the value you want to use is there otherwise return a fallback string `{{ placeHolderMsg ? placeHolderMsg : 'Default placeholder'}}`
e.g.

```
<ui-select-match 
  class="ui-select-match" 
  ng-attr-placeholder="{{ $ctrl.userEntity.loginName ? 
        userEntity.loginName : 'Please select an option'}}">
  {{$select.selected.loginName}}
</ui-select-match>
```